# Call an overwritten method in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, superclass, super

I want to call a method (*foo*) in Coffee-script from a subclass. I know I can do this with `@foo` if I didn't overwrite *foo* in the subclass, or with *super* if I did overwrite it and I'm calling from the subclass' foo method.

However, I would like to call superclass' foo method from subclass bar method. How can this be done?

Comment: That's some pretty broken OOP you're trying to do there.

Comment: Might be I was a bit too enthusiastic with code-reuse.

Comment: yeah, I suggest you refactor a bit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need this but ...

```
class A
  foo: ->
    console.log 'A'

class B extends A
  foo: ->
    console.log 'B'
  bar: ->
   A::foo.call @

new B().bar()
```